# iPython Set Up Missing Steps?

Tags: python, ipython

The documentation for iPython can be found here:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/index.html

They have the section labeled "Installation" which says all you need to do is run `pip install ipython`. Okay, I did that.

Then the next section skips to using ipython.

Okay, so it must be installed, right? Enter `python` to enter your interactive prompt and... nothing looks different... but just try using its features! `?`! Nope, that's a `SyntaxError`, just like normal.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is installed already. The issue is, ipython doesn't change what the standard python program does - instead, it adds itself as a seperate program. So to start an ipython interactive session instead, run `ipython` from the command line instead of `python`.

It's actually mentioned half way down this page:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/index.html

Because, of course the very basic step of running a program belongs half way through the documentation on how to run it, well after the directions for how to install it have already ended.